# Quasar file picker change text color of selected file name in q-file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

Quasar **File Picker** component to change the text color of selected file name in `<q-file>`.
[image]

the text file selected is test.odt, how can I change it's text color for example **Red**?

```
<q-file
  standout
  class="registration-field text-red"
  bg-color="blue-2"
  v-model="registrationNumber"
  color="red"
>
  <template v-slot:prepend>
    <q-icon name="o_insert_photo" size="24px" color="blue" />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <div class="attachment text-grey-14">File</div>
  </template>
</q-file>
```

I've tried using style props **color="red"** and it's not working.

anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use the `file` slot and add `text-red` class and it works.

```
<q-file
  standout
  class="registration-field text-red"
  bg-color="blue-2"
  v-model="registrationNumber"
  color="red"
>
  <template v-slot:prepend>
    <q-icon name="photo" size="24px" color="blue"/>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <div class="attachment text-grey-14">File</div>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:file="{ index, file }">
    <div class="ellipsis text-red relative-position">
      {{ file.name }}
    </div>

    <q-tooltip>
      {{ file.name }}
    </q-tooltip>
  </template>
</q-file>
```

Codepen- https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/wvWzOoV

Comment: where is the start of `</q-chip>`, I'm getting format error

Comment: it's WORKING!!! thanks. but I had to remove `</q-chip>` it causes format error & I also remove `{ index }` because it's not being used here.